# how to insert a increment id in dynamo db? can anybody explain with example

Tags: node.js, amazon-dynamodb

I am trying to do auto_increment id using insert item in dynamo db. so i'm not able to find any solution. Please help me with example

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please have a look at [the tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour). You may also want to check [What topics can I ask about](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic), and [How to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), and [The perfect question](http://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/), and how to create a [Minimal, Complete and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Post the code you have tried and the errors you have received. Be as specific as possible as it will lead to better answers.

Answer (score 0):

The recommended approach is use UUID for partition key. Refer this [post](https://forums.aws.amazon.com/message.jspa?messageID=312527).

You can use the **UUID module** in node js to generate the partition key.

**Sample code below:-**

```
var docClient = new AWS.DynamoDB.DocumentClient();
var uuid = require('uuid');

var table = "Order";

var params = {
    TableName:table,
    Item:{
        "orderId": uuid.v1(),
        "productName": 'Milk'
    }    
};

console.log("Adding a new item...");
docClient.put(params, function(err, data) {
    if (err) {
        console.error("Unable to add item. Error JSON:", JSON.stringify(err, null, 2));
    } else {
        console.log("Added item:", JSON.stringify(data, null, 2));
    }
});
```